# Reduced chi-square too low (close to 0) after weighted fit - convolution integral - Python lmfit

Tags: curve-fitting, convolution, model-fitting

I'm fitting the following data where t: time (s), G: counts per second, f: impulse function (mm/s):

```
    t     G     f 
    0   4.58    0
  900   11.73   (11/900)
 1800   18.23   (8.25/900)
 2700   19.33   (3/900)
 3600   19.04   (0.5/900)
 4500   17.21   0
 5400   12.98   0
 6300   11.59   0
 7200   9.26    0
 8100   7.66    0
 9000   6.59    0
 9900   5.68    0
10800   5.1     0
```

Using the following convolution integral:

[image]

And more specifically:

[image]

Where: `lambda_1 = 0.000431062` and `lambda_2 = 0.000580525`.

The code used to perform that fitting is:

```
#Extract data into numpy arrays
t=df['t'].as_matrix()
g=df['G'].as_matrix()
f=df['f'].as_matrix()
#add parameters
params=Parameters()
params.add('a',value=1)
params.add('b',value=0.7)
params.add('c',value =1)
#define functions
def exp(x,k):
    return np.exp(-x*k)

def residuals(params,x,y):
    A=params['a'].value
    B=params['b'].value
    C=params['c'].value

    dt=x[2]-x[1]
    model = A*(np.convolve(exp(x,lambda_1), f))[:len(x)]*dt+B*np.convolve(exp(x,lambda_2), f)[:len(x)]*dt+C
    weights=1/np.sqrt(y)
    return (model - y)*weights

#perform fit using leastsq
result = minimize(residuals, params, args=(t,g))
final = g + result.residual
print(report_fit(result))
```

It works, however I obtain a very low reduced chi-square (around 0) when I multiply the residual to be minimized by the weight (1/np.sqrt (g) (weighted fit). If I do not taken into account the weight (non-weighted fit), I obtain a reduced chi-square of 0.254. I would like to obtain a reduced chi-square around 1.

Answer (score 1):

A reduced chi-square far below 1 would imply that your estimate of the uncertainty in the data is far too large.   If I read your example correctly, you are using the square-root of `G` as the uncertainty in `G`.  Using the square root is a standard approach for estimating uncertainties in values dominated by counting statistics.

But... your `G` is a floating point number that you describe as counts per second. I might assume counts per second over 900 seconds.

If that is right (and we assume for simplicity no significant uncertainty in that time duration), then the uncertainties should be 30x smaller than you have them.  That is, you are using

```
g_values = [4.58 ,  11.73,  18.23] 
g_uncertainties = sqrt(g_values) = [2.1401, 3.4249, 4.2697]
```

but the uncertainties in the counts would be `sqrt(g_values*900)`, and so the uncertainties in counts per second by `sqrt(g_values*900)/900 = sqrt(g_values)/30`.

More formally, the uncertainties in a value representing "counts per time" would add the uncertainties in counts and the uncertainties in time in quadrature.  But again, the uncertainties in your time are probably very small (or, at least your time data implies that it is below 1 second).

Comment: thank you but doing what you say my reduced chi-square becomes very high...the total counts are not exactly g_values*900, i have another array for the total counts and i used for computing the uncertainties of my data...however i obtain a reduced chi-square of approximately 5...Maybe this is due to the fact that the expected counts per second aremainly less than 5 ??? Thanks

Comment: In order to get reduced chi-square around 1.0 you need a) a good fit, and b) an accurate estimate of the uncertainties in the data you are actually modeling.  I have no idea what sort of problem you are working on, so I cannot tell you what the uncertainties in your data are, but if you are taking the square root of a **count rate**, you definitely are not going to have an accurate estimate of the uncertainties in your data -- that doesn't pass a dimensional analysis....  The uncertainties in *y* must have the same units as *y*.

Comment: I'm modelling data related to the activity (counts per second) of a radionuclide (radioactive decay) which corresponds to the nets counts (total counts - background counts). My estimate uncertainties are square root of total counts ( net counts + background counts ) divided by 900s. I'm not taking the square root of the count rate….and the uncertainties about my background counts are negligible. My question is, maybe the reduced chi square is not an accurate statistical test to check the goodness of my fit (since the expected values are very low and my sample size small) ? Thank you

Comment: For the example code in your question, it sure looks like you *are* taking the square root of the count rate.  You have `weight = 1./np.sqrt(y)` in your objective function and pass in the column labeled 'G'  in your file as `y`.  How is that anything other taking the square root of a count rate?